# error in parsing json string in javascript

Tags: json

I am using JSON in Javascript for first time in my project of asp.net. I am new to it.
I have successfully created a JSON string on page load and stored it in a hidden field.
Now, in Javascript when I try to eval or parse that string, it do not parse it.

Please help. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
var jsonText = $("#hiddenJson").val();

var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonText);       

//var jsonObject = eval("(" + jsonText + ")");

alert(jsonObject.user[0].Gender);

//---- alert gives [object Object]

//------- value of jsonText is

"[ { "user": [ { "Gender": "M", "Minage": "28", "Maxage": "24", "MaritalStatusId": "2,3", "ChildrenPreferencesId": "0", "PersonalValueId": "1", "MinHeight": "6", "MaxHeight": "1", "BodyTypeId": "0", "ComplexionId": "0", "HealthAttributeId": "1", "SpecialCaseId": "1", "ReligionId": "3,5", "CasteId": "1,6", "MotherTongueId": "", "QualificationLevelId": "2,3", "QualificationFieldId": "", "WorkingWithId": "4,5", "ProfessionArea": "3,4", "WorkingAsId": "3,4", "IncomeId": "3", "DietId": "0", "SmokeId": "1", "DrinkId": "2", "CountryId": "4,5", "ResidencyId": "", "PartnerDescription": "" }] } ]"
```

Comment: It's printing that because the `Gender` field is an object, not a string (or anything it can evaluate to a readable string). We would need the structure definition of `Gender` to assist further.

Comment: This is valid JSON, what is the error you are getting while trying to parse it?

Comment: Please refrain from reposting your questions. If you have details to add, edit the original question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON object itself is an array:

```
alert( jsonObject[0].user[0].Gender );
```

See an example at http://jsfiddle.net/GTLX3/

Answer (score 5):

if you're using double quotes for the members of the json object, then put the whole string in single quotes instead, like

```
var jsonText = '[ { "user": [ { "Gender": "M", "Minage": "28", "Maxage": "24", "MaritalStatusId": "2,3", "ChildrenPreferencesId": "0", "PersonalValueId": "1", "MinHeight": "6", "MaxHeight": "1", "BodyTypeId": "0", "ComplexionId": "0", "SpecialCaseId": "1", "ReligionId": "3,5" }] } ]'
```